# why form is not submitting

Tags: javascript, php, html

```
    <html>
    <head><br></head>
    <body>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function validate()
    {

        var pass1=document.form1.pw.value;
        var user=document.form1.name.value;
                if(user.length==0)
                {
                         alert( "Username Should not be blanck");
                         document.form1.name.focus();
                         return false;
                }
            if (pass1.length == 0) 
            {
                alert("You must enter  password");
                document.form1.pw.focus();
                return false;
             }
              if(pass1.length<4)
              {  
                  alert("Password length should not be less than 4 characters");
                   document.form1.pw.focus();
                    return false;    
              } 
               //alert("submit");
           document.form1.submit();
                return true;          
    }
    </script>
      <form action="Authenticate1.php" method="post"  name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data"  ">
    <table width="40%"  border="1"> 
     <tr> 
     <td width="20%"> </td> 
     <td width="40%"> </td>
     <tr> 
    <td><b><h2></h2>Login:</td>
     <tr><td>USER NAME&nbsp&nbsp<input type="text" name="name"></td></tr>
    <tr><td>PASSWORD&nbsp&nbsp<input type="password" name="pw"></td></tr> 
    <tr><td><input type="button" name="submit" value="LOGIN" onclick="return validate()";> </td>
     </tr>  </tr>
    </table> 
    </form> 
    </body> 
    </html>
```

please help me
 can u tell me why my form is not submitting is there any error. Please help me.
i have done validation by using input type of button as submit then it works but i wanted to submit it by JS

Comment: did your console tell you any error?

Comment: the form will send if user click on submit button, in this code when user click on button will run the validate() function in javascript. javascript don't allow your form to submit!

Comment: @Kermani That is so wrong

Comment: And what if all the conditions are met? Do you see `document.form1.submit()` at the end of the validate function?

Comment: @asprin Yes you  are right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form isn't submitting, because of this error:

[image]

On close inspection of the code, it looks like your form html has a typo:

```
<form .... enctype="multipart/form-data"  ">
------------------------------------------^ you have extra double-quote
```

So, update this line of html into this:

```
<form action="Authenticate1.php" method="post"  name="form1" id="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Then rename your submit button's name into something other than `submit` like this:

```
<input type="button" name="submitBtn" value="LOGIN" onclick="return validate()";>
```

Now it should work.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like there's an ambiguity issue because you've named your submit button `submit`:

```html
<input type="button" name="submit"
                           ^^^^^^ Here.
```

When you do:

```javascript
document.form1.submit();
```

It's trying to treat `submit` as an object, and you get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Simply change the name of your button.